# EC2 instance unreacheble after rebooting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm making this question because I [checked this similar one](https://serverfault.com/questions/935811/ec2-instance-stuck-at-unreachable-login-after-assigning-elastic-ip-and-rebooting?newreg=02a3a522cc234ded8966f7654b7f6d9b) and I don't know why the owner accepted the first answer, since it did not help him to achieve his goal. I'm not able to add comments too, so I guess adding another question is the way.

I'm facing the **exactly same issue**. Everything as working awesome but after reboot, my instance is failing the status check on instance side. I double check this steps:

1. Make sure that Security Group has open inbound access to TCP port 22
   from your IP or from everywhere as described above.
2. Verify that the instance really has the Elastic IP assigned. In
   EC2->Instances->i-abcd1234... -> look for Public IP and ssh to that,
   e.g. `ssh -v ubuntu@111.111.111.111.`
3. I tried to create another instance with the same security group, and It worked perfectly
4. I tried to change the type of my instance from `micro` to `small` and it keeps failing.

This is the screenshot of the server and it looks really weird to me that it's stuck on a login screen when I'm not able to access it to input the information.

Screenshot of EC2 server:

[image: screenshot of ec2 server]

Since I'm on free tier, I'm not being able to receive technical help and the only way to solve it is if somebody had the same problem before to help me here.

Thank's to anyone that take your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try for system status check failure is to stop the instance then start it, which moves you to new hardware. Since you have an instance status check failure that probably won't help, but it probably won't hurt either.

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) says the likely causes of instance status check failure are:

- Failed system status checks
- Incorrect networking or startup configuration
- Exhausted memory
- Corrupted file system
- Incompatible kernel

Easiest thing to try is stop the instance, increase the size so it has more RAM, then start it. Of course double check your security group and NACLs.

The next thing to do is stop the instance, attach the primary volume to another instance as a data volume, and look at the logs on the instance. Do any remediation required, detach and set it up on the original instance, and try again.

Unfortunately this one has no quick answer. Sometimes it's easier to just create a new instance from a snapshot or backup.